# DISM Apply-Image out of Windows PE without formatting - loading screen

Tags: windows, dism

I am looking for a way to reapply the wim image without losing any users data out of Windows PE. So far my script looks like that:

```
$TSProgressUI = New-Object -COMObject Microsoft.SMS.TSProgressUI
$TSEnv = New-Object -COMObject Microsoft.SMS.TSEnvironment
 
$OSDDownload = $TSEnv.Value("osDownload01")
$LogsDirectory = $TSEnv.Value("_SMSTSLogPath")

$wimImagePath = "$OSDDownload\install.wim"
$systemDriveLetter = "S"

Remove-Item -Path "$($env:_OSDDetectedWinDrive)Program Files\WindowsApps" -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Remove-Item -Path "$($env:_OSDDetectedWinDrive)ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository" -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$wimIndex = (Get-WindowsImage -ImagePath $wimImagePath | Where-Object {$_.ImageName -eq "Windows 10 Enterprise"} | select -property ImageIndex).ImageIndex
dism /Apply-Image /ImageFile:$wimImagePath /index:$wimIndex /ApplyDir:$($env:_OSDDetectedWinDrive)
#dism /Image:$($env:_OSDDetectedWinDrive) /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:$wimImagePath /LimitAccess


Get-Partition | Where-Object {$_.GptType -eq "{C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B}"} | Set-Partition -NewDriveLetter $systemDriveLetter
cmd /c """$($env:_OSDDetectedWinDrive)Windows\System32\bcdboot.exe"" ""$($env:_OSDDetectedWinDrive)Windows"" /s $($systemDriveLetter): /f UEFI"
```

However, doesn't better what I try after the apply-image command, my windows installation afterwards stays in the loading screen. If I do a reset I receive the message "The computer restarted unexpectedly or encountered an unexpected error".

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks
md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the way I wanted it to work did not work. At the same time I didn’t want to add the 21H2 Image as an extra upgrade package into SCCM because from 20H2 to 21H2 you only need the enablement package.

So here is what I did:

First I created a new package with all setup files from the disc but without the install.wim and I replaced the boot.wim with a 0KB boot.wim file. Additionally I added  the folder SMSTSPostUpgrade, which I took just from a previous Upgrade TS. This includes the SetupComplete.cmd and SetupRollback.cmd. But this was only for another intended way, see comments below. Finally I got a package size of around 275MB.

In my SCCM Task Sequence I did following steps:

1. Downloading content:

I used the function "Download Package Content" to download once the Vanilla Install Image and the new created Setup content files. Both I saved with a variable (osImage; osSetup)

2. Creating a hardlink to add the install.wim to the setup folder. Probably you could maybe also just move it there:

   ```
   $TSEnv = New-Object -COMObject Microsoft.SMS.TSEnvironment

   $OSDDownload = $TSEnv.Value("osImage01")
   $OSDSetup = $TSEnv.Value("osSetup01")

    fsutil hardlink create "$OSDSetup\sources\install.wim"
   ```

   "$OSDDownload\install.wim"
3. I called the "Upgrade Operating System" function with the source path %osSetup01% and the Edition index 3 (in that case Enterprise)

After that I can use my task sequence also as a repair one.

Btw. Instead of the "Upgrade Operating System"  function I also tried a powershell script, but I couldn’t find a way to manage the reboots:

```
#$TSProgressUI = New-Object -COMObject Microsoft.SMS.TSProgressUI

$TSEnv = New-Object -COMObject Microsoft.SMS.TSEnvironment
 
$OSDDownload = $TSEnv.Value("osImage01")
$OSDSetup = $TSEnv.Value("osSetup01")
$OSDUnattended = $TSEnv.Value("osUnattended01")
$LogsDirectory = $TSEnv.Value("_SMSTSLogPath")

$wimImagePath = "$OSDDownload\install.wim"
#$wimUnattendedPath = "$OSDUnattended\Unattend.xml"
#$systemDriveLetter = "S"

Remove-Item -Path "$($env:_OSDDetectedWinDrive)Program Files\WindowsApps" -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Remove-Item -Path "$($env:_OSDDetectedWinDrive)ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository" -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$wimIndex = (Get-WindowsImage -ImagePath $wimImagePath | Where-Object {$_.ImageName -eq "Windows 10 Enterprise"} | select -property ImageIndex).ImageIndex

#dism /Image:$($env:_OSDDetectedWinDrive) /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source:$wimImagePath /LimitAccess

#dism /Apply-Image /ImageFile:$wimImagePath /index:$wimIndex /ApplyDir:$($env:_OSDDetectedWinDrive) /Apply-Unattend:$wimUnattendedPath
#Get-Partition | Where-Object {$_.GptType -eq "{C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B}"} | Set-Partition -NewDriveLetter $systemDriveLetter
#cmd /c """$($env:_OSDDetectedWinDrive)Windows\System32\bcdboot.exe"" ""$($env:_OSDDetectedWinDrive)Windows"" /s $($systemDriveLetter): /f UEFI"

Write-Output "cmd /c start /wait $OSDSetup\setup.exe /ImageIndex $wimIndex /auto Upgrade /quiet /noreboot /EULA accept /Telemetry Disable /postoobe $OSDSetup\SMSTSPostUpgrade\SetupComplete.cmd /postrollback $OSDSetup\SMSTSPostUpgrade\SetupRollback.cmd /postrollbackcontext system /DynamicUpdate Disable /compat IgnoreWarning /InstallFrom $OSDDownload\install.wim"
cmd /c start /wait $OSDSetup\setup.exe /ImageIndex $wimIndex /auto Upgrade /quiet /noreboot /EULA accept /Telemetry Disable /postoobe $OSDSetup\SMSTSPostUpgrade\SetupComplete.cmd /postrollback $OSDSetup\SMSTSPostUpgrade\SetupRollback.cmd /postrollbackcontext system /DynamicUpdate Disable /compat IgnoreWarning /InstallFrom $OSDDownload\install.wim

return 3010
```

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.